# Conversion from string "X.X" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am working on a web application in asp.net and I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8.
when I run the project by Visual Studio and use IIS Express (by default) it works fine.
but When I publish the project on IIS a problem occurs about converting from string value contains "3.5" to Double:

**Conversion from string "3.5" to type 'Double' is not valid**
this error appears only when i use iis on my computer.
but it works properly when i upload the same published application to my host server.

I think it depends on my culture settings.
I tried to change  "Decimal symbol" from
Controlpanel > Region > Format(first tab) > Additional Settings 
but i cant solve my problem yet.

Comment: You keep saying IIS, but I think you mean something else. Also, *what* project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert into global.asax

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."